# How to draw a honeycomb, consisiting of "mercedes"-like elements?

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, maxscript, 3ds

What is the best way to build a 3D honeycomb-pattern in 3ds max (by means of maxscript), consisting of simple elements (like is shown in the picture). Each element is a 'mercedes-logo'-like shape. Each element is not sewed to the adjacent ones.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple object distribution problem? 
You can get this already just using the built-in Array tool. But if you need code, you should model one of those tripod-like objects and then create instance-copies of that and place them at regular intervals.

Computing those intervals is simple trigonometry: Assuming one leg of your 'mercedes logo' has length l, the next instance needs to be placed at x-position += 4*l*(cos 30) and so forth; this will give you the first row of red tripods.

The blue row needs an x-offset of half that value, plus a y-Offset of 2*l*(sin 30) (and a rotation obviously).

Rinse, repeat.